# What is the meaning of "For reasons of sentiment"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "For reasons of sentiment"?

This is the full sentence:

> “**For reasons of sentiment**, I would like part of my ashes to be mixed up with Mama’s, and both her ashes and mine put side by side in the columbarium. We were joined in life and I would like our ashes to be joined after this life.”

Answer (score 1):

You could also say:

> **For sentimental reasons**, ...

*reason* means why you want to follow the detail of the phrase that follows it (your plan).

*sentimental* is an adjective modifying *reason* (emotional rather than logical), so we can understand the reason better.

Comment: ahh, i see, thanks for making it easy to understand!